# Is it possible to change the recaptcha icon with a different colored one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, recaptcha

I've been trying to change the captcha icon/logo in the recaptcha v2, I tried to use normal CSS for it at first but that didn't help. Then I tried to use jQuery to see if the Iframe was fully loaded and then to change it with jQuery.

The icon/logo is loaded from one of the Google website via a CSS file. In the file they call upon the element `.rc-anchor-logo-img`. This is a div that has the icon/logo in it. The CSS to this div is:

```
.rc-anchor-logo-img {
    background: url(https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/logo_48.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This is the original one that is provided by Google

[image]

and I want to change it to this one

[image]

If someone could help me that would be perfect of course. But I have the feeling that it won't be changeable.

Either way, my thanks for taking the time to read this or to comment. Lovely day.

Comment: I think it's actually against Google's branding guide to manipulate the color of their icons, so there is good reason why they do not allow the option. If you read Google's terms of service: "These terms do not grant you the right to use any branding or logos used in our Services. Don’t remove, obscure, or alter any legal notices displayed in or along with our Services."

Comment: Have you tried overriding the CSS

Comment: @Terry Thank you for your comment. You make a good point. It would be a bit strange as well. So it makes sense that its not possible. To bad but understandable. Thank you either way for the time.

Comment: If the image is in the iframe, there is no way to change it. Same Origin Policy prevents you from touching it. Live with the blue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not change the CSS of HTML inside an iframe. it is also against Google policies to make changes on this.
 however, it is possible by adding an image over the iframe.
try putting captcha code inside a div, then add the image (transparent png icon) inside the same div too. your image should be in an absolute position to its parent div. by changing the CSS of image (left, top) try to overlap it on the icon.